# Javascript: Add loop:false to this carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove the loop function on this fiddle:

## http://jsfiddle.net/DYFj8/

Every detail is in there

This is the basic strucutre needed for the carousel to work:

```
<!-- Please see Fiddle for live beauty code -->
<!-- Or This Pastebin for the javascript: http://pastebin.com/uaegeqt7 -->

<!-- This javascript below is the minified version of the above -->
<script src="http://img3.wsimg.com/fos/sbc/94080/js/jquery.slide-this.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-slidethis="id|sliderexample" class="slidethis-prev left-arrow">Previous</a>

        <ul class="slidethis" data-slidethis="id|sliderexample,animate|true,delay|0,speed|250">
            <li>First item</li>
            <li>Second item</li>
            <li>Third item</li>
        </ul>

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-slidethis="id|sliderexample" class="slidethis-next right-arrow">Next</a>
```

But again, everything is in the Fiddle

Comment: Minified code? No thanks.

Comment: The fiddle isn't minified - I've added this note to the question - Sorry!

Comment: pick a slider with options you want. There are tons of them to chose from

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: Please, open the Fiddle, I think it's very clear... If it's not let me know

Comment: @Lucas B:Fiddle is not minified but the js that you provided is !!!..Try to use another slider or provide the unminified js

Comment: I've added it to the question: http://pastebin.com/uaegeqt7

Comment: That's the minified version....

Comment: Take a look at this http://responsiveslides.com/, http://responsiveslides.com/themes/themes.html

Choose out of these..Simply and easy to implement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely a better way of doing this. However, given that the code is so hard to read, this is what I came up with.

Modify function `f`, it's located close to the top.

```
function f() {
    l = $(".slidethis");
    m = $(".slidethis-prev").hide();
    k = $(".slidethis-next");
    $('.slidethis li:first').data('first', true);
    $('.slidethis li:last').data('last', true);
    b(l);
    b(m);
    b(k);
    c();
    i();
    a()
}
```

And then modify function `h`, located close to the bottom.

```
function h(p, n) {
    var o = e(p)["stslides"];
    if (n == "next") {
        var item = o.shift();
        if (o[0].data('last')){
          k.hide();   
        }else{
         k.show();
            m.show();
        }
        o.push(item);
    }
    if (n == "prev") {
        var item = o.pop();
        if (item.data('first')){
         m.hide();   
        }else{
         m.show();   
            k.show();
        }
        o.unshift(item)
    }
}
```

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ad8X4/5/)

Comment: That's wonderful Vic, thank you! Only the last arrow don't disappear here yet - I have 6 <li>, it removes the arrow after it loops goes trough the 6, plus 2... I'll adapt your fiddle to reproduce it

Comment: Found the problem, the last arrow only disappears when the last <li> is on the left! Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ad8X4/6/

Comment: Found a way to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/ad8X4/7/    Can't thank you enough Vic!!